# How to apply aggregate pipeline operators for entire collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a scenario where I need to apply aggregate pipeline operator for all the properties in the collection. Here how I have achieved it.

```
model = { 
      age: Number ,
      risk: Number,
      retireage: Number,
      wealth:  Number
    };
```

I need to sum all together and get the average.

What I did:

```
    $group :{
             _id: '',
             age : {$avg : {$sum: ['$age',value]}},
             risk : {$avg : {$sum: ['$risk',value]}},
             retireage : {$avg : {$sum: ['$retireage',value]}},
             wealth : {$avg : {$sum: ['$wealth',value]}},

    }
```

Is there a way I can apply `{$avg: {$sum:'$this'}}` at once for all the properties in the collection.

Comment: is the issue that you don't know all the properties you will need to average? or just that there are many of them and you don't want to type out the similar looking like for each?

Comment: why do you need $sum and $avg?   taking average of a single number is just that number, so can you explain in English what you are trying to calculate?

Comment: Just edited post to answer your second comment. For the first comment - Yes I know all the properties but it has more than 20 properties, so I don't want to write 20 lines to get the result. Also, I need to do $trunc as well. Since $trunc is not supported inside $group have to write another 20 lines inside $project. So I'm wondering if there is a way to write the statement that is applied to each and every property separately.

Comment: You could do it if the collection was relatively small but it seems pointless - you only have to write the aggregation once and you can run it many times, why would you want to optimize for writing rather than running?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify an `_id` value of `null` to accumulate values of all documents and then use [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator to get the sum of each field :

```
Model.aggregate([
    { 
        $group : 
        {  
            _id: null, 
            age: { $avg: { $sum: '$age' } },
            risk: { $avg: { $sum: '$risk' } },
            retireage: { $avg: { $sum: '$retireage' } },
            wealth: { $avg: { $sum: '$wealth' } }
        } 
    }
]);
```

**EDIT** If you have multiple fields to group you can use a loop to create your query:

```
var fields = ['age', 'risk', 'retireage', 'wealth', ...];
    groups = { _id: null };

fields.foreach( function (field) {  
    groups[field] = { $avg: { $sum: '$' + field } };
});

Model.aggregate([
    { 
        $group : groups
    }
]);
```

Comment: the result should be like this                                                                                 {
             _id: '',
             age : avegAge,
             risk : avgRisk,
             retireage : avgRetireage,
             wealth : avgWealth,

    }                                                                                                                     need to get average for each property

Comment: need this `{
             _id: '',
             age : avegAge,
             risk : avgRisk,
             retireage : avgRetireage,
             wealth : avgWealth,

    }  `

Comment: I got the result, with ' ' empty string as well. But the issue is I have around 20 properties in this model so I have to repeat this for 20 times and need to add $trunc as well. Unfortunately cannot use $trunc inside the $group then I have to add another pipe for $project with $trunc for all 20 properties.

Comment: You can use for loop to do that for you, I updated my answer, please take a look